# How to stop execution of apex:actionFunction on the basis of condition

Tags: visualforce, actionfunction

I am calling two action functions one after the other. In first action function I am doing DML operation and in second action function i am calling API method.

I want to stop execution of second action function based on some condition.

My sample code is as below, please let me know what I am missing here.

VF Page:

```
<apex:commandButton value="Save" onclick="InsertRecord_JS();" />
<apex:actionFunction action="{!saveRecord}" name="InsertRecord_JS" oncomplete="CallWebService_JS();"/>
<apex:actionFunction action="{!sendRecordToexternal}" name="CallWebService_JS" />
```

Controller methods:

```
public void saveRecord(){
    if(validationPassed){
        insert record;
    }
}

public void sendRecordToexternal(){
    //calling API method here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in two ways, first is recommended if you are trying to do some input validations.

Define a function in JavaScript, and call the action function conditionally inside that.

```
function foo(){
    if(condition){
         // call action function
         InsertRecord_JS();
    }
}
```

and call the function `foo` from the button click.

```
<apex:commandButton value="Save" onclick="foo();" />
```

The second approach is to use apex params: [Passing multiple Parameters in ActionFunction in Visualforce](https://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/passing-parameter-in-actionfunction-in-visualforce/#:%7E:text=Calling%20Apex%20Method%20from%20the,used%20to%20achieve%20this%20functionality.).
Use this only if you want to send data to the apex and check conditions over there. But it's better to handle validations at the client-side only.